# Why %% changes to single % in generated BATCH automatically?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, command-line, parameters

I don't understand why while I generate new batch file from primary file one parameter (%%A) automatically changes to single (%A)

Prime batch file:

```
echo FOR %%A in (1k\*.txt) do ... (whatever) >> another.bat
```

As result I become a new another.bat with single line:

```
FOR %A in (1k\*.txt)
```

And this another.bat doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To echo a single `%` you need to double it to `%%`.

To echo two `%` you need to do it twice, as in `%%%%`.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` command replaceable parameter needs one percent sign, but inside a batch file percent signs need to be escaped, doubling the percent sign. That is the reason for the output you see. You write two characters but they represent only one. And you get one in the output.

If you need two percents in output, you need to escape each of them, so you need to write four percent signs to get two in the output.